# how to render an object with two flux fields without blocking?

Tags: spring, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

I want to render an object composed of two mono or flux elements (below a code snippet):

```
 Mono<List<NodeDTO>> nodeDTOFlux = this.webClient
            .get()
            .uri(NODES_WITH_LIMIT + limit)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError,
                    response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(
                            msg -> Mono.error(new ApiCallException(msg, response.statusCode())))
            )
            .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Node>() {
            }).map(node -> nodeMapper.toNodeDTO(node))
            .collectList();



    Mono<List<EdgeDTO>> edgeDTOFlux = this.webClient
            .get()
            .uri(EDGES_WITH_LIMIT + limit)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError,
                    response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(
                            msg -> Mono.error(new ApiCallException(msg, response.statusCode())))
            )
            .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Edge>() {
            }).map(edge -> edgeMapper.toEdgeDTO(edge))
            .collectList();
```

I tried with zip() method but it's not what I aim to do
I tried to return an object like this

```
    GraphDataDTO graphDataDTO = new GraphDataDTO();
    graphDataDTO.setEdgeDTOS(edgeDTOFlux);
    graphDataDTO.setNodeDTOS(nodeDTOFlux);
```

I have a result in my console but the object returned
{
"nodeDTOS": {
"scanAvailable": true
},
"edgeDTOS": {
"scanAvailable": true
}
}
the return is done before getting all the flux.. is there any solution without blocking !
thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried with zip()?

Comment: return  Mono.zip(nodeDTOFlux, edgeDTOFlux).map(
                Tuple2::toList
        ).map(objects -> )
               .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);

Comment: It combines all together in the same object but I want to get s.th like  {
    "nodeDTOS": [ {    }, {  } ..],
    "edgeDTOS": [ {    }, {  }.. ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```java
return Mono.zip(nodeDTOFlux, edgeDTOFlux)
      .map(tuple2 -> GraphDataDTO.builder().nodeDTO(tuple2.getT1()).edgeDTO(tuple2.getT2()).build())
```

It creates a Tuple of `NodeDTO` and `EdgeDTO` and maps it into `GraphDataDTO`.